# Adding "for ____ in ______ try:" statment into my python script returns "Forbidden: received 403 HTTP response"

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a Python script that monitors a subreddit and comments based on keywords using PRAW. I can get it to take my credentials and to choose my subreddit and keywords but as soon as I add the `for____ ..` statement it breaks my code.

```
import praw

# Set up PRAW with your Reddit application credentials
reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="-",
    client_secret="-",
    user_agent="-",
    username="-",
    password="-",
)
# Choose the subreddit and keywords
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('Testing')
keywords = ['watermelon', 'testies', 'farts']
response = "TITE"

# Stream comments and search for keywords
for comment in subreddit.stream.comments(skip_existing=True):
    if any(keyword in comment.body for keyword in keywords):
        print(f"Keyword found in comment by {comment.author}: {comment.body}")
        comment.reply(response)
```

I can get an exit code 0 on everything before "# Stream comments...."

Here are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    for comment in subreddit.stream.comments(skip_existing=True):
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/models/util.py", line 138, in stream_generator
    for item in reversed(list(function(limit=limit, **function_kwargs))):
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 63, in __next__
    self._next_batch()
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/models/listing/generator.py", line 89, in _next_batch
    self._listing = self._reddit.get(self.url, params=self.params)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/util/deprecate_args.py", line 43, in wrapped
    return func(**dict(zip(_old_args, args)), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 712, in get
    return self._objectify_request(method="GET", params=params, path=path)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 517, in _objectify_request
    self.request(
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/util/deprecate_args.py", line 43, in wrapped
    return func(**dict(zip(_old_args, args)), **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 941, in request
    return self._core.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 328, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/behole/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 267, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)
prawcore.exceptions.Forbidden: received 403 HTTP response

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The title mentions a `try:` statement, but it does not appear in the code. Can you provide this code?